# How do I make atlas with same pages but different layer sets?

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have a project in QGIS with multiple layers that I have to render separately. E.g. parks and distances to them (their buffers), travel time isochrons (interpolation with colors), density heatmap, etc.

I have several areas of interest, and for each of these I want to generate N pages. Each page is not a single layer, but a combo (heatmap comes with contour lines for better readability).

[image: areas of interest]

Right now I can render one atlas for just one setup (a page is shown below). How can I scale this to several layer setups?

[image]

Comment: Afraid I can't help for QGIS, or even tell you it's possible, but in ArcGIS this is accomplished with page definition queries - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87683/ which might give you an idea toward solving in QGIS.