# Using Data Driven Pages - like function for full map layer symbolization?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, data-driven-pages

I have a hexagon layer, and in each hexagon is a count of how many trees are in the hexagon. There are several species within this data. I am trying to create a definition query that will run through each species type the same say Data Driven Pages runs through different polygons. The primary difference is that the map extent will remain the same, but the data being displayed is being changed. In the end, I would like a separate map for each species. Is there a simple way to do this? Do I need to use arcpy or is there a feature within ArcGIS that can handle this?

Comment: possible duplicate of this question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87683/how-to-make-map-book-of-pages-with-same-area-shown-but-different-layers-turned-o

Comment: it's close, but it does not address how to select a data category within a layer as opposed to simply turning off/on separate layers

Comment: PROBERT's answer to the question @Carolyn linked to will solve your problem. You need to use a page definition query and create a custom layer to use as your index layer.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't something ArcMap does particularly well. Depending on your workflow and data type, I'd say the page definition query would be your best bet. You'll need to reformat your attribute table so that you have one feature per hexagon per species. Set up a DDP with an index layer of overlapping/identical extents and a page name attribute that lists the species. Then set up a page definition query in your data layer so that only those features with the appropriate species tag are displayed for that page. If you have more questions, maybe add a screenshot or two of what you are doing?

Comment: I do it through identical pages and placing corresponding layers in groups named after page. Small script goes through pages switching visibility of all groups but current off and exporting each page to PDFs. I can post script if this is close to what you are talking about.